# /etc/sudoers vs /etc/sudoers.d/ file for enabling sudo for a user

Tags: sudo, yocto

I am using Yocto to build image for a board. I have disable the `root` user.
I am adding a new user, lets say `adminuser1`. As it looks to me there are two options to make `adminuser1` as admin.

- Add `adminuser1` to sudoers in /etc/sudoers
- Create a new file `/etc/sudoers.d/0001_admin1` and add a line `adminuser1 ALL=(ALL) ALL`

The default `/etc/sudoers` has the `sudo` group commented `# %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL`

I am trying to understand, as to which one is a better approach in terms of security:

- Shall I add `adminuser1` to `sudo` group and uncomment the `# %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL` in `/etc/sudoers`
- Adding `/etc/sudoers.d/0001_admin1` and adding only `adminuser1 ALL=(ALL) ALL` in the file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The choice between `sudoers` and `sudoers.d` has nothing to do with security, but everything with maintainability.

- By uncommenting the `sudo` group line in `/etc/sudoers`, you can add all users that need to have sudo access to the `sudo` group. This may or may not be easier to do than adding a new file in `sudoers.d`, depending on your setup. However, changing the shipped configuration file may make things harder (e.g., if there is an update of your distribution which would overwrite the sudoers file, you have to ensure that your change is retained).
- By adding a file to `/etc/sudoers.d`, you don't have the update issue that I hint to above, but then if you there explicitly add configuration for `adminuser1` rather than the `sudo` group, adding more users to have sudo rights will require more files to be added to `/etc/sudoers.d`; this may or may not be more involved than just adding them to the right group.

There is no one way which is "best"; and there certainly isn't a security issue based on "which file do I configure sudo rights in". Just consider the upsides and/or downsides of both methods, and use whichever works best for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia:

> the principle of least privilege (also known as the principle of minimal privilege or the principle of least authority) requires that in a particular abstraction layer of a computing environment, every module (such as a process, a user, or a program, depending on the subject) must be able to access only the information and resources that are necessary for its legitimate purpose.

This means that the option 2 is the best one because you can tailor the permission of your adminuser1. With option 1, when in the future you will add adminuser2 to the sudo group, then they will have the same privileges which don't let you tailor the privileges the two users.

Moreover, always use *visudo* to edit the sudoers file.

HTH

Comment: While the principle of least privilege makes sense, it has nothing to do with *where* you configure things. It's perfectly possible to configure "may do anything as root" in `/etc/sudoers` as well as a file in `/etc/sudoers.d`. Therefore, this doesn't actually answer the question at hand.